# How do I define a variable in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In Haskell, I can do

```
Prelude> [(y*3, y+4) | x<-[0..5], let y=x^2]
[(0,4),(3,5),(12,8),(27,13),(48,20),(75,29)]
```

What's the equivalent in Python, without repeating the power operation, as I would need in

```
>>> [((x**2)*3, (x**2)+4) for x in range(5)]
[(0, 4), (3, 5), (12, 8), (27, 13), (48, 20)]
```

I can of course emulate the Haskell code with a lambda, but that doesn't feel very Pythonic...

```
>>> [(lambda y: (y*3, y+4))(x**2) for x in range(5)]
```

Comment: Briefly: with a nested generator. `[(a*3, a+4) for a in (x**2 for x in range(5)]`

Comment: Maybe a little silly, but now (3.8) you can assign variables in if statements. ```[(y * 3, y + 4) for x in range(5) if ~(y := x**2)]``` the ~ is used because when x is 0, it doesn't set the y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't assign a variable in a comprehension, but you can use a nested generator expression, which does what I think you want (without a lambda function).

```
[(y*3, y+4) for y in (x**2 for x in range(5))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Assignment is always a statement in Python; list comprehensions can only contain expressions.

Comment: Really? I _can_ achieve the goal with a lambda, so I don't really buy that it can only be done with expressions. Just... isn't there a more idiomatic solution than with a lambda?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> [(x*3, x + 4) for x in map(lambda y: y**2, range(5))]
[(0, 4), (3, 5), (12, 8), (27, 13), (48, 20)]
```